# How to change unselected item color in showMaterialScrollPicker

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

[screenshot image for showMaterialScrollPicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oaRyu.png)
Hey guys , I'm new flutter learner so can I change the color of unselected items in showMaterialScrollPicker ?

Hey guys , I'm new flutter learner so can I change the color of unselected items in showMaterialScrollPicker ?

```
        child: GestureDetector(

      onTap: (){
        showMaterialScrollPicker(
            context: context,
            items: GpaCubit.get(context).grades,
            selectedItem: GpaCubit.get(context).gradeValues[index],
            title: 'Pick your grade' ,
            headerTextColor: Colors.white,
            backgroundColor:  calculatorColor  ,
            // backgroundColor:  Colors.teal,
            headerColor: Colors.cyan.withOpacity(0.7),
            buttonTextColor: Colors.white,
            showDivider: false,

            onChanged: (value){
             GpaCubit.get(context).changeGradeValue(value, index) ;
            },
        );
      },
      child:
      GpaCubit.get(context).gradeValues[index] == 'null' ?
      Center(
        child: Text(
          'Grade' ,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.grey,
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
      ) :
      Center(
        child: Text(
          GpaCubit.get(context).gradeValues[index] ,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.cyan,
            fontSize: 22,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
          ),
        ),
      ) ,
    ),
```

Comment: Can you include more about `showMaterialScrollPicker` which package you are using for this

Comment: it's flutter_material_pickers: ^3.1.4+1

Comment: Seems like to don't expose the builder, is it ok to have alternative?

Comment: why not if it does the same function

Comment: This method doesn't provide any builder, also the textStlye is depending on bodyTextTheme

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CupertinoPicker` , both provide the similar UI, the  `showMaterialScrollPicker` using Stack widget.

```dart
Future<dynamic> customPicker(BuildContext context) {
  return showDialog(
    barrierDismissible: false,
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      return StatefulBuilder(
        builder: (context, setState) => AlertDialog(
          title: Text("Select Grade"),
          content: CupertinoPicker(
            itemExtent: 60,
            onSelectedItemChanged: (value) {
              selected = grades[value];
              setState(() {});
            },
            children: grades
                .map(
                  (e) => Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "$e",
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: selected == e
                              ? Colors.green
                              : Colors.cyanAccent),
                    ),
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    },
  );
}
```